# Eclipse ignores breakpoint in library

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I'm trying to make a parallel version of the SIFT algorithm from the [VLFeat](https://github.com/vlfeat/vlfeat) library.

The program works properly, but when I place a breakpoint at line 979 of [this](https://github.com/vlfeat/vlfeat/blob/master/vl/sift.c) code it's totally ignored by the debugger.

I think that the problem is that I open the library code just using the File->Open File option, but I don't know how to do otherwise. How can I make the debugger stop there?

Comment: is it a DLL? and loaded dynamically by an executable or linked against it?

Comment: I'm working on Linux, so no, it's not a DLL. I think against an executable, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: maybe your `.so` file isn't loaded when you put the breakpoint. You have to enable pending breakpoints.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.vlfeat.org/install-c.html) you can use only the binary of this library, no `.so` is involved and `extern C` is used

Comment: can you check gdb console / use `info break` after placing the breakpoint to see if it worked?

Comment: I have no idea about how to use it, however this is weird: I've tried to modify the source code and recompile it. The binary produced by the new make display the differences from the old code (`Hello world` prints) while the Eclipse code doesn't. It's like it's using the  old version of it.